# Duration of UIView animation being ignored

Tags: swift3, uiviewanimation

I'm having this tricky problem, I'm not even sure on how to explain it (can't show too much code because NDA)

My view have an custom element, a colored bar which have a curve animated based on user scrolling a table. That works great, when user scroll, delegated is called and the method who update the colored bar curve is called too. So, the curve is updated "in a loop".

Now I have to move it programatically.
When the animation occurs, the colored bar is not animated, instead, suddenly change to the final state.

I know why this is happening.

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.headerHeightConstraint.constant = self.maxHeaderHeight
            self.updateHeaderAlpha()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            onComplete()
        })
```

the constrain value is seted to the final value and the updateHeaderAlpha (this one set the curve value) is called just once. So, the animation did occurs but the bar change in the beginning to the final state.

The "solution" should be call the updateHeader method in "every cycle" of the animation, but I can't do that. I have already tried:

- Add an observer: Just no, this didn't work
- Call the method recursively: There is no animation (or it happens too fast)
- Use a timer
- Use a sleep/delay (yeah, sorry)
- User repeat and beginFromCurrentState in the animation and change:

  self.headerHeightConstraint.constant = self.maxHeaderHeight

for

```
self.headerHeightConstraint.constant -= 1
```

This produces a weird animation, not solving the problem and creating a new one
- Recursively call the animation until the value of the constraint is the desired one.
Awful as it sounds, is the approach that is closer of what I want, except, that the animation completely ignores the animation duration and take it a very long time. I.E:

```
func collapseHeader(_ onComplete: @escaping (()->Void) = {}) {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
            self.headerHeightConstraint.constant -= 1
            self.updateHeaderAlpha()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            if self.headerHeightConstraint.constant <= self.minHeaderHeight + 1 {
                onComplete()
            } else {
                self.collapseHeader() {
                    onComplete()
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

(I know this isn't supposed to be do)

Notice the animation duration is  0 (I have tried, 0.2, 0.02, 10, 0.5, etc..), but the animation takes something like 25-30 seconds to finish.

The other approach I have tried, is to change de offset of the table to "simulate" the user interaction, but this produces very weirds side effects on the animation and the view in general.

Considering that modifying the colored bar isn't an option.

Anyone knows why the animation called recursively is taking too long?

Or even better, Anyone can think in a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Write your own layer with a custom animatable property. Plenty of examples around. `CAAnimation` is the key.

Comment: Thanks pal, that's the hint I needed